# how to count number of turtles on a set of patches at a particular instance in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Can we count number of turtles on a set of patches or on a single patch at some particular time instance (say for in a tick).

```
set turtle-at-setpatches count turtle-on patches with [ (pxcor >= 9 and pxcor <= 13) and (pycor <= 9  and pycor >= 2)]
```

I gets the count with this code, but is this count is on the basis of ticks by default. what i need is number count on a particular tick(or instance). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to question as asked:

```
if (ticks = 10) [
  set turtle-at-setpatches 
    count turtles-on patches with [ 
      (pxcor >= 9 and pxcor <= 13) and (pycor <= 9  and pycor >= 2)
]
```

A possibly better answer: collect the data for every tick in a table. E.g.,

```
extensions [table]
globals [setpatches turtles-on-setpatches]

to setup
  ;compute setpatches only once
  set setpatches patches with [ (pxcor >= 9 and pxcor <= 13) and (pycor <= 9  and pycor >= 2)]
  crt 500
  set turtles-on-setpatches table:make
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  table:put turtles-on-setpatches ticks (count turtles-on setpatches)
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that means if we don't take any tick value then it by default counts the total turtle on the given patch for each tick. If suppose we assume 1tick as 1sec then we can say that in 1sec count is 10 (suppose). Is it so?

Comment: The first version simply sets your global `turtle-at-setpatches` *once*, when `ticks = 10`.  After than, it won't change unless you change it elsewhere.

Comment: The second version introduces a table and creates a record: for each tick, the table uses `ticks` as the key and the count of turtles as the value.  This gives you a record of what happened for the entire simulation.  You can get the value for any period from the table.  E.g., `table:get turtles-on-setpatches 10` would retrieve the value recorded when `ticks = 10`.

Comment: table seems a bit like overkill here — why not just add a number to the end of a list at each tick, using `lput`? regardless, good answer.